# Python libxml2: xpathEval vs xpathEval2?

Tags: python, libxml2

In libxml2 help I found that:

```
xpathEval(self, expr)
      # Selecting nodes using XPath, a bit slow because the context
      # is allocated/freed every time but convenient.

xpathEval2(self, expr)
```

It is confusing that xpathEval2 doesn't include further comment. What is the difference among them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version there is no difference, look at the python code:

```
    def xpathEval2(self, expr):
      return self.xpathEval(expr)
```

But there's a section commented out which shows that the method was intended for speeding up parsing, though had some memory leaks:

```
#    # Selecting nodes using XPath, faster because the context
#    # is allocated just once per xmlDoc.
#    #
#    # Removed: DV memleaks c.f. #126735
```

check your implementation for more accurate info.